# "ArrowInvalid: Can't unify schema with duplicate field names" read parquet files from s3 using dask;

Tags: python, dask, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

using a query I dump data from redshift to parquet

```
UNLOAD
('
SELECT
     delivered_at
    , flow_name
    , variant_name
    , user_id
') TO
            's3://data/raw/redshift/all_campaigns'
            IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::XYZ:role/redshift'
            FORMAT AS PARQUET
            maxfilesize 96 mb
            ALLOWOVERWRITE
            MANIFEST;
```

from the other end using `dask` I try to read a chunk of this data

```
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://data/raw/redshift/all_campaigns0079_part_00.parquet')
```

/Users/fanbuch/Devel/NyRec/EDA.ipynb Cell 7' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = dd.read_parquet('s3://data/raw/redshift/crm/was_clicked/all_campaigns0079_part_00.parquet')

```
File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/deeprec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py:460, in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, calculate_divisions, ignore_metadata_file, metadata_task_size, split_row_groups, chunksize, aggregate_files, parquet_file_extension, **kwargs)
    457 if index and isinstance(index, str):
    458     index = [index]
--> 460 read_metadata_result = engine.read_metadata(
    461     fs,
    462     paths,
    463     categories=categories,
    464     index=index,
    465     gather_statistics=calculate_divisions,
    466     filters=filters,
    467     split_row_groups=split_row_groups,
    468     chunksize=chunksize,
    469     aggregate_files=aggregate_files,
    470     ignore_metadata_file=ignore_metadata_file,
    471     metadata_task_size=metadata_task_size,
    472     parquet_file_extension=parquet_file_extension,
    473     **kwargs,
    474 )
    476 # In the future, we may want to give the engine the
    477 # option to return a dedicated element for `common_kwargs`.
...
File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/deeprec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status()

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/deeprec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: Can't unify schema with duplicate field names.
```

I am sure I don't have identical columns. Please help me improve the question quality if it is not clear.

**update**

```
dask version        : '2022.6.0'
pyarrow version     : '8.0.0'
fastparquet version : '0.8.1'
```

I also have asked the question on their gir issue page [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9251)

Comment: Can you share the dask and pyarrow/fastparquet version you are using?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I updated the question with those libraries version

Comment: cool, there was some big change recently in interaction with pyarrow/parquet files, so one quick thing to try is to use an older dask version (e.g. `2022.1.0`, if that's feasible within your project).

Comment: I can see there's a related GH issue here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9251

Comment: did you look at the time :D that's me - with an approaching deadline !

Comment: yes, I realised it's likely you, but wanted to link it here (it's a community practice to link same questions across different platforms)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there were indeed columns with identical colnames.